# Expanding a parent div horizontally to fit its floated children

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a parent div with a variable number of equally sized child divs floated left.  I want the parent div to expand to the width of the children no matter what, even if it means overflowing its own container.

Is there a way to do this naturally with HTML/CSS?

Example (The stretchable div would wind up being 180px wide):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="stretchable-div">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    ...
</div
```

**CSS:**

```
.child {
   width: 60px;
   height: 60px;
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: did you end up figuring out how to do this?

Comment: Ok, it looks like the easiest way to do this would be to use JavaScript to dynamically increase/decrease the width of the container element, within a parent with overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this example the stretchable-div element will bust out of its parent, and stretch to its children.

***[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/seB5F/)***

**css**

```
#parent{
    width:200px;
    height:180px; 
    background:red;
}

#stretchable-div{
    background:blue;
    position: absolute;
}

.child {
   width: 60px;
   height: 60px;
   float:left;
}
```

**Markup**

```
<div id="parent">Im a parent
    <div id="stretchable-div">
        <div class="child">a</div>
        <div class="child">b</div>
        <div class="child">c</div>
        <div class="child">c</div>
        <div class="child">c</div>
        <div class="child">c</div>
        <div class="child">c</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Loktar- Thank you, but I have two questions- See my modified version of your example: http://jsfiddle.net/seB5F/12/  1) When I add more elements, or push the absolute div rightward, the elements start to wrap against the edge of the frame.  2) I also added overflow:hidden to the parent div, but still see all the stretchable div.  Why can't I have the stretchable div stretch to width, with any overflow hidden?  Can you explain this?

Comment: Ok to answer the first question, its because position absolute, takes it out of the document flow, so thats why the overflow has no effect on the stretchable div, change it to relative and its hidden

Comment: @Loktar- You answered my question, but I still have a problem- I want the overflow to be hidden.  To do that I need to make the container position:relative, but this causes the contents to wrap.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm I thought you wanted the contents to stretch regardless, even outside of their parent. Now you want the opposite, stretch only to the parents width than hide?

Comment: I do want them to stretch regardless, but then I want the option to hide the overflow or not.

Comment: ah ok I see.. thats a tricky one, let me work on it for a minute. Might want to take the answer away from me in case someone else comes up with a better solution first.

Answer (score 3):

Just like @Pizzicato's example, but using `overflow:hidden` to clear the parent `div`: http://jsfiddle.net/dSjv4/.

There's a great article about positioning and clearing div's on A List Apart [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/) (near the end of the article).

Comment: @Nathan- Thanks, but but your example won't allow the parent div to overflow its container. See http://jsfiddle.net/dSjv4/14/

Answer (score 1):

you can add `display: inline-block;` for the parent element. To work in ie7 also you need to use `display:inline;zoom:100%;` instead.

So a possible css for what you need is this:

```
#stretchable-div {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto; /* clear the floats */
    *display:inline; /* ie7 hack even better use conditional comment */
    zoom:100%;
}
```

**example:** http://jsfiddle.net/8JJSf/

Comment: @Sotiris- Thanks, but your example won't allow the parent div to overflow its container.  See http://jsfiddle.net/8JJSf/4/.

Comment: @Yarin correct, to overflow the container it needs also `position:absolute` for `#stretchable-div`

Comment: @Sotiris- Yes that works, but then you wouldn't need display:block-inline, right?

Comment: @Yarin yes in this case it's not required.